# Activity starts first activity when finish() is called instead of returning to previous one

Tags: android, android-activity, android-preferences

I have a flow like that in my app:

InitialActivity -> PreferencesScreen -> AnotherActivity

where InitialActivity and AnotherActivity are ordinary classes that just extend `android.app.Activity`. PreferenceScreen extends `android.preference.PreferenceActivity` and it is a singleton class.

When I'm done in AnotherActivity and want to return to PreferencesScreen, I use finish() in it, but instead of returning to PreferencesScreen, it just opens another InitialActivity instance. When I press back button, I can see my previously created PreferenceScreen and InitialActivity screens.

So what do you think causes this weird situation? Is it about AnotherActivity class, or is it about PreferenceScreen's being singleton? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Here is the code that calls finish() on AnotherActivity:

```
private class ConnectServer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(AnotherActivity.this,
                "", "Please wait...", true, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        // Do some work, send some data to server

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
        Toast.makeText(AnotherActivity.this, "Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        dialog.dismiss();
        finish();
    }

}
```

and here is the PreferenceListener that opens up AnotherActivity:

```
new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

                startActivity(new Intent(PreferenceScreen.this, AnotherActivity.class));
                return true;
            }
        }
```

InitialActivity in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <activity android:name=".InitialActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: It's probably something to do with AnotherActivity. Perhaps you are calling startActivity() just before calling finish()? Please post some code.

Comment: I posted the code that calls finish() on my activity. I am sure that the communication with server completes successfully, so nothing interesting happens there.

Comment: Okay. That is weird. Do you do anything in the lifecycle methods of AnotherActivity (onPause, onStop, onDestroy)?

Comment: Nope, I did not override any of these methods except onCreate.

Comment: I'm scraping the bottom of the barrel here, but do you perhaps start a second initialActivity somewhere (perhaps in PreferencesScreen, before starting AnotherActivity)?

Comment: I even searched inside my code but no, I do not do that either. I just updated the post once again, there is a specific preference element which opens AnotherActivity, and that's it.

Comment: Does logcat show a second instance of initialActivity being started? Also, what attributes do you set for initialActivity in the manifest?

Comment: Nope, I traced the logcat while the second InitialActivity is being started, but even the name of the class did not appear. In the mean time only unexpected log was `03-17 19:25:19.724: INFO/global(207): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.` and that's it.

Comment: I don't know if you are still interested in but, I figured out that when I start any intent from PreferenceScreen, it just changes the order of the activities in the stack. In other words, it does not start a new intent, it just returns to the first one and put the PreferenceScreen behind that one. But why does the stack change?

Comment: If your manifest declares the PreferencesScreen activity to have a launch mode of "singleInstance", it will launch AnotherActivity in another task. I don't know exactly how this could cause a second copy of InitialActivity when you call finish(). Perhaps you can discover a clue from the detailed description in the guide topic [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html).